# How can I see who is following me?

Tags: support

How can I see my followers on Stack Exchange websites?

Comment: I'm following you.  Not in a creepy way, I swear.  Not creepy at all.

Comment: It is possible, because your profile picture is familiar to me. How can I remove you from the face of the earth? :D

Comment: What do you mean "following"? See who viewed your profile?

Comment: No, I meant follower how it is in the social networks. Namely, someone who get notifications when I ask new questions, for instance.

Comment: You might confuse this site with Twitter. We are different.

Comment: @rene, I understood. Mine was just a question. I think it is better in this way: no followers.

Comment: Closest thing is subscribing to the user's RSS feed (e.g. [yours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/309189)), but there's no way to know who did it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't. Following people is simply not possible on Stack Exchange; we're a Q&A site focused on content, not a social network. You can follow tags and Area 51 proposals, but nothing else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I remember that someone was following me, but if you say so, I am likely wrong.

Comment: After all, also the epigraph in your profile states that life is complex: it has both real and imaginary parts :D :D

Comment: Note also that one can "Favorite" a question, which is, for all intents and purposes, "following" it.

Comment: Great activity you have there in your feed that I follow https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/295232 ;)